# Running queries in BigQuery without being a project User

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

It seems the only way to share a dataset so that another person can run queries on the tables from the dataset is to make that person a Project **user**. See [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#predefined_iam_roles)

This means that the user would have access to **all** the datasets on the project. This seems to me that is is highly inconvenient. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For user to run query - user need to have [`bigquery.jobs.create`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions) permission

If your user already has this permission in any other project - you can just simply share your dataset with this user with Can View Access Level

If user is new and does not have yet bigquery.jobs.create in any other project - you can just add this user to your project with this permission only.

[image]

And still you need add this user to ACL for that 
specific dataset

**Important**: Please also note - if you give user permission to create jobs in your project  - you will be `billed` for respective queries.
If user has its "own" project and only has view access to you data - in this case bill goes to user's project

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for your answer.